# A-Frame user swipe effect for 360 Image

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

I have a 360 Image using aframe.io library.  And I would like to see how to create a "throw" effect.  [Not sure what the effect calls] When user swipe left or right, the 360 images will rotate/spin to either direction and eventually finish after sometime (perhaps depends on how hard the swipe is?).

I am thinking of having a a-animation within a a-sky can do the trick, but I would like to ask someone whether this is the right approach.

The effect would be similar to 
http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/

Thank.

```html
<a-sky id="vr-sky">
          <a-animation attribute="rotation"></a-animation>
        </a-sky>
        
        
<!-- Or use animation component -->
 <a-sky id="vr-sky"
          animation__rotation="property: rotation; dur: 2000; easing: easeInOut; to: 0 360 0">         
        </a-sky>
```

Comment: Can't user super-hands as state below as the screen will bounce left and right when mouse is down while dragging

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using [`super-hands`](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component) to handle the swipe-to-throw and [`aframe-physics-system`](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system) to handle the spinning and deceleration (with a little help from [`aframe-physics-extras`](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-physics-extras))

[Live Demo](https://cumbersome-leopard.glitch.me/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Swipe to spin photosphere</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v2.1.0/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-extras/dist/aframe-physics-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene physics="gravity: 0">
    <a-assets>
      <a-mixin id="static" static-body="shape: sphere; sphereRadius: 0.2"></a-mixin>
      <!-- the z position of the grabber determines the leverage/force for swipes -->
      <a-mixin id="grabber" physics-collider position="0 0 -25"
               collision-filter="collisionForces: false"
               super-hands="colliderEvent: collisions;
                            colliderEventProperty: els;
                            colliderEndEvent: collisions;
                            colliderEndEventProperty: clearedEls">
      </a-mixin>
      <img id="pano" src="https://your image url here" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
      <video id="video360" src="https://your video url here" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    </a-assets>
    <!-- progressive-controls sets up mouse/touch input -->
    <a-entity progressive-controls="maxLevel: gaze; gazeMixin: grabber"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="bottom" mixin="static" position="0 -100 0"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="top" mixin="static" position="0 100 0"></a-entity>
    <!-- use an entity with a sphere because a-sky seems to have its rotation locked down -->
    <!-- angularDamping sets the deceleration rate and the constraints limit rotation to Y axis -->
    <!-- src can be #pano or #video360 -->
    <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100" material="src: #pano; side:front" grabbable 
              scale="-1 1 1"
              dynamic-body="angularDamping: 0.5"
              constraint__1="type: pointToPoint; target: #bottom; collideConnected: false; pivot: 0 -100 0"
              constraint__2="type: pointToPoint; target: #top; collideConnected: false; pivot: 0 100 0">
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I click the live demo link, I see a flat 360 image instead.  Could you please let me know how to run it properly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "flat 360 image". Here's the direct link to the running A-Frame scene: https://cumbersome-leopard.glitch.me/ does that help?

Comment: "flat" means it is not in a sphere or a-sky, as if I am just viewing the original image.

Comment: Like its just a plain HTML page showing the image instead of in a 3D scene? That should only happen if the A-Frame library isn't loading, but that page is pulling it from their CDN. What's your browser? Does the console show the A-Frame loading message (A-Frame Version: 0.7.0 (Date 22-09-2017, Commit #570c623e)). Have you tried a hard refresh?

Comment: It is loading now, I didn't know why it didn't work the first time.  Thanks.  It does work and it spins according to how hard I "swipe" with the mouse.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same logic and make the sky a-entity a videosphere so we get the same behavior for 360 video?

Comment: @Alocus It looks like the only difference would be to point the sphere's material source to a video asset instead of an image https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/material.html#built_in_materials_src

Comment: @Alocus It will probably be more obvious with a video that the example code I gave actually shows a reversed image. You'll need to set `scale` to `'-1 1 1'` like they do in `a-videosphere` https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.7.0/src/extras/primitives/primitives/a-videosphere.js

Comment: I will give it a try.  Thank you very much

Comment: It works for both image and video.  This is awesome.  The only thing I need to figure out is the scale="-1 1 1", because with this setting, both image and video don't display at all.  Thanks @M Murphy

Comment: For other people, scale="-1 1 1" will work with side: front instead of back.  This is awesome!

Comment: @Alocus could you make an edit to my answer with the correct scale and side settings? Also I'd love to try out the video version when you have something sharable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160226/discussion-between-alocus-and-w-murphy).