# A-Frame super-hands to swipe 360 video and image

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe, aframe-super-hands

This is more of a follow up question on 
[A-Frame user swipe effect for 360 Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518373/a-frame-user-swipe-effect-for-360-image).

Swipe mouse cause the video or image to spin.  Nonetheless, the mouse is not able to grab hold of the scene and drag around.  Because when it is dragged to the left, the scene goes to the right and bounce back to the left as if the super-hands is conflicting with the camera one wants to go one way the other spin the other.  Or the super-hands is trying very hard to spin while the mouse is still grabbing the object so it bounces the scene left and right.

I tried:

1. `look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true"` set to true and false for the camera to help align with spinning
2. `invert=true` for the sky a-entity.

But I don't think the above are the problem. So I tried:

3. For the sky a-entity, I tried to set the resistance higher ondragstart, then lower ondragend to reduce the bounce effect.  As setting angularDamping to 1 will prevent the sphere to spin.

   dynamic-body="angularDamping: 1"  // prevent spinning

   // The DOM seems to get updated, but has no effect on the behavior.
    ondragstart="this.setAttribute('dynamic-body', {angularDamping: 1})"
    ondragend="this.setAttribute('dynamic-body', {angularDamping: 0.5})"

Please kindly let me know what I did wrong and point me to the right direction.  Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Swipe to spin photosphere</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v2.1.0/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-extras/dist/aframe-physics-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene physics="gravity: 0">
  <!-- Original camera, now it is embedded within progressive-controls -->
  <!--<a-camera id="vr-camera" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 90 0" fov="60"></a-camera>-->
  
    <a-assets>
      <a-mixin id="static" static-body="shape: sphere; sphereRadius: 0.2"></a-mixin>
      <!-- the z position of the grabber determines the leverage/force for swipes -->
      <a-mixin id="grabber" physics-collider position="0 0 -25" collision-filter="collisionForces: false" super-hands="colliderEvent: collisions;
                            colliderEventProperty: els;
                            colliderEndEvent: collisions;
                            colliderEndEventProperty: clearedEls">
      </a-mixin>
      <img id="pano" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <video id="video360" src="https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </a-assets>
    <!-- progressive-controls sets up mouse/touch input -->
    <a-entity progressive-controls="maxLevel: gaze; gazeMixin: grabber">
        <a-camera id="vr-camera" look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: false" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 90 0" fov="60"></a-camera>
    </a-entity>
    <a-entity id="bottom" mixin="static" position="0 -100 0"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="top" mixin="static" position="0 100 0"></a-entity>
    <!-- use an entity with a sphere because a-sky seems to have its rotation locked down -->
    <!-- angularDamping sets the deceleration rate and the constraints limit rotation to Y axis -->
    <!-- src can be #pano or #video360 -->        
    <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100" 
         material="src: #pano; side:front" grabbable 
         scale="-1 1 1" dynamic-body="angularDamping: 0.5" 
         constraint__1="type: pointToPoint; target: #bottom; collideConnected: false; pivot: 0 -100 0" 
         constraint__2="type: pointToPoint; target: #top; collideConnected: false; pivot: 0 100 0">
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The issue is that the grabbing action initiates a lock constraint between the view and the sky, so the mouse is turning the scene, but it is also turning the background with it. I can't think of a way to do this using only existing components. Maybe ditch `super-hands` and do custom component to call applyForce on the sky body on mouseup http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_applyForce

Comment: Thanks @W.Murphy I will try something else